# Why is the band Persian Risk named as such?

Tags: bands, names

I accidentally stumbled upon these guys on Spotify and couldn't help but ask why they chose to go with this name. The Wikipedia entry doesn't say much and a Google search brought nothing so I'll have to turn to the collective wisdom of Stack Exchange for an answer. Seems like a very unlikely name for a British metal band to me so I'd like to know if they ever discussed the etymology.

Comment: Current version of PR has an FB page - maybe you could ask via that ?  Often, names for bands either have some meaning, or the name is some random thing  which just stuck